# Como enviar SMS gratuitamente utilizando PHP?

Tags: php, sms

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de enviar SMS gratuitamente para celulares do Brasil.
Já vi alguns sistemas PHP com esta função, e gostaria de ter esta função no meu sistema também.

Comment: Há diversas soluções pra isso, desde pagas até gratuitas, por isso a pergunta é 'ampla demais'.

Comment: Ano que vem (2014) nas eleições, vai ter muita gente procurando essa resposta.

Comment: é simples: precisa dum serviço externo para fazer isso. talvez limite a pergunta para saber quais serviços existem, ou escolhe um serviço e pergunte como usar?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Antigamente dava pra mandar usando o **Google Agenda**, porém sempre para o mesmo número verificado, usei por um tempo pra sistema de alertas.

Se precisar realmente enviar **SMS** a partir do seu sistema, existem duas alternativas, ambas pagas:

1) Usar um serviço de mensageria que irá te cobrar por mensagem. Existem vários, no Brasil conheço apenas o zenvia.com.br (não é marketing, não tenho relação com a marca).

- Nessa caso, você faria a integracão com o sistema da empresa e enviaria as mensagens via Internet (API). Eles tem módulos para vários sistemas, e bibliotecas prontas para várias linguagens, devidamente documentadas.

2) Usar um modem acoplado ao servidor

- Solução apenas quando existe servidor local, eu uso e sai muito barato. Usando um modem 3G, para instalar no Linux geralmente é complexo. Depois de tudo configurado, chamo via CLI, usando

  ```
  echo '$mensagem' | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT $numero -unicode
  ```

Comment: Interessantes estas opções. De acordo com minhas pesquisas existe um forma de utilizar o Google Voice. Conheçe algo sobre ele?

Comment: Achei bastante interessante a sua ideia. Já que disse que utiliza dessa forma poderia nos mostrar como em mais detalhes?

Comment: Fiz uma busca rápida aqui, e você pode usar o aplicativo [SMS Gateway](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway&hl=en) em um smartphone Android. Ele expõe uma API HTTP que você pode chamar para mandar os alertas. Aí seria só uma questão de deixar o telefone constantemente ligado, e expor ele através do seu roteador, possivelmente usando um serviço de DNS dinâmico. Essa é uma opção bem *low budget*, e não sei quanto a confiabilidade.

Comment: Muito bom @MarcoAurélio, vou pesquisar a respeito. Muito obrigado.

Comment: No Caso do Zenvia, eles tem módulos para vários sistemas, e bibliotecas prontas para várias linguagens, devidamente documentadas.
Usando um modem 3G, pra instalar no linux geralmente é complexo, depois de tudo configurado, chamo via CLI, usando 

echo '$mensagem' | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT $numero -unicode

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar SMS via código o que acontece basicamente é que você usa uma API de alguma operadora que ao enviar sua solicitação para a mesma ela vai acionar um aparelho celular que vai enviar seu SMS.

Não conheço nenhum serviço desse tipo nacional gratuito, somente pagas basta entrar em contato com uma operadora de sua preferência que eles vão liberar uma documentação para você começar usar(pagando o devido custo claro).

Caso queira serviços internacionais é possível encontrar alguns gratuitos, basta perguntar pro nosso amigo google.

Comment: Prezado Guerra. De acordo com minhas pesquisas existe um forma de utilizar o Google Voice. Conheçe algo sobre ele?

Comment: Dataol, atualmente o Google Voice não está permitindo esse envio de sms via API. E como você falou nacional imaginei que ele não serviria. Ate onde eu sei nacional e gratuito não existe =/

Comment: Só eu acha que mandar buscar no google sem citar exemplos não responde a questão?

Comment: Você pode tentar o http://www.twilio.com/ . Da última vez que verifiquei eles mandavam mensagens para o Brasil.

Comment: Ok @MarcoAurélio vou verificar

Comment: Traquilo @ViníciusFrança, obrigado pelo comentário