# Como enviar SMS via PHP

Tags: php, sms

Existe alguma classe que é conhecida aqui, que realiza o envio de SMS via PHP? Precisa de algum Gateway?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20/como-enviar-sms-gratuitamente-utilizando-php